# How do I display the baseline value of a previous year in an Excel graph?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-charts

I have a line chart with 12 months of rolling data. I was wondering if there was a way to insert a data label or symbol or something on the vertical axis to indicate the baseline value for the previous year (value will not change). I can add another series but i would like just a little icon on the axis for the baseline value?

Would inserting a ClipArt be the easiest way?

Thanks everyone in advance!

Comment: Adding new series and plotting on second Y axis would work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly suggest using the error bar method for adding target value lines to your graph. I use it a lot as it's a solid and proven method of showing performances for the previous month, target KPI for current period, etc.

Granted there's a learning curve but it's easy once you get the hang of it. Best of all, it can go vertical, horizontal, or both.

An exceptional tutorial, courtesy of Jon Peltier: [Add a Horizontal Line to a Column or Line Chart: Error Bar Method.](http://peltiertech.com/Excel/Charts/AddLineHorzErrBar.html)

Hope this helps.